# Creating a csv file from formatted ascii input

Tags: csv, text-formatting

I am using Linux.

I have a file of the following format

```
; Header info
;--+-----+--+----+-+----------------
;Co TASK# ID PROP X Remarks
;de (full desc.)
;--+-----+--+----+-+----------------
AAA P00_1 000Lean - not yet done
AAB P00_2 11 Fat  X 20190606
AAC P00_3 1  MidleX canceled
```

and want it to be converted into this csv file of this format

```
Code;Task#;ID;PROP;X;Remarks
AAA;P00_1;000;Lean;-;not yet done
AAB;P00_2;11;Fat;X;20190606
AAC;P00_3;1;Midle;X;canceled
```

Fields are of varying length but maximum length is up to the column of the corresponding '+' -> see line starting with 'AAC' and the field saying 'Midle' for example.

First step would be to determine the columns of the '+'-signs in the header format description and the to inserting a ';' at those columns for each row by respecting the "oversized" fields like "Midle" (see above).

How can I acchieve this with awk or sed or ... under Linux?

Cheers!

Comment: GNU/awk has a `FIELDWIDTHS` variable that deals with columnised data. You can create the list of columns from any of the `+--` lines. Extracting the headers is too much trouble unless you have many different file sets -- even then I would prefer to hard-code all the header variations and pick one by matching some distinctive feature, to avoid processing arbitrary text.

Comment: Hi have you tried my answer? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705881/195582

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed schema (I have assigned to it the name `input-schema.csv`)

```
column,start,length
Code,0,4
Task,4,6
ID,10,3
PROP,13,5
X,18,2
Remarks,20,17
```

you can use [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and run (using you input file, I have assigned as name `input.csv`)

```
<input.csv grep -v '^;' | in2csv -f fixed -s input-schema.csv | csvformat -D ";"
```

to have

```
Code;Task;ID;PROP;X;Remarks
AAA;P00_1;000;Lean;-;not yet done
AAB;P00_2;11;Fat;X;20190606
AAC;P00_3;1;Midle;X;canceled
```

Comment: This is neat, but the user in the question seems to want to determine the column widths and headers dynamically from the `;`-lines at the top.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have written "if you have a fixed schema ", and I wait for a comment from @mcr. If needed, I would start from `printf '%s\n' ';--+-----+--+----+-+----------------' | grep -o . | grep -n '+'`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk, using `FIELDWIDTHS` for [Processing Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html). Get the field widths from the table outline. And remove trailing whitespaces for every field.

```
BEGIN { FS = "+"; OFS = ";" }
NR == 2 { 
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f = (f ? f " " : "") length($i)+1
  FIELDWIDTHS = f
  print "Code;Task#;ID;PROP;X;Remarks"
}
!/^;/ {
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i)
  print
}
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Code;Task#;ID;PROP;X;Remarks
AAA;P00_1;000;Lean;-;not yet done
AAB;P00_2;11;Fat;X;20190606
AAC;P00_3;1;Midle;X;canceled
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
NR == 2 {
        for (i = 1; i <= length(); i++) {
                if (substr($0, i, 1) == "+" || i == length()) {
                        fieldWidths[++fieldNr] = i - prevFieldEndPos
                        prevFieldEndPos = i
                }
        }
}

NR > 5 {
        fieldNr = 0
        for (i = 1; i <= length(); i += fieldWidths[fieldNr]) {
                fieldVal = substr($0, i, fieldWidths[++fieldNr])
                gsub(/^[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]*$/, "", fieldVal)
                printf "%s", (i > 1 ? ";" : "") fieldVal
        }
        print ""
}' infile
```

Output (without processing the header part becasue it's not clear that how it's populated):

```
AAA;P00_1;000;Lean;-;not yet done
AAB;P00_2;11;Fat;X;20190606
AAC;P00_3;1;Midle;X;canceled
```